# LibGDX's TexturePacker with gradle

Tags: android, libgdx, texturepacker

I am attempting to create a gradle task which runs TexturePacker according to the instructions [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer#running-texturepacker). (Note that I am using Android Studio and its directory structure rather than Eclipse.) I first added the following to the Android Studio project's `build.gradle`:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.tools.texturepacker.TexturePacker
task texturePacker << {
  if (project.ext.has('texturePacker')) {
    logger.info "Calling TexturePacker: "+texturePacker
    TexturePacker.process(texturePacker[0], texturePacker[1], texturePacker[2])
  }
}
```

This gave the error

> unable to resolve class com.badlogic.gdx.tools.texturepacker.TexturePacker

Moving the `texturePacker` task to `build.gradle` in the desktop project produces the same error. According to http://www.reddit.com/r/libgdx/comments/2fx3vf/could_not_find_or_load_main_class_texturepacker2/, I also need to add `compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"` to the root `build.gradle` under the desktop project's dependencies. When I do so, I **still** get the same error.

So I have several questions:

1. Where is the correct place for the `texturePacker` task? Which `build.gradle` do I put this in?
2. How do I solve the dependency issue and the `unable to resolve class...` error?
3. How do I specify the input and output directories and the atlas file when running this with gradle? (Assuming the first two questions are solved.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got it working by adding gdx-tools to my buildscript dependencies:

```
buildscript{
    dependencies {
       ...
       classpath 'com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:1.5.4'
    }
}
```

by doing this, my desktop's build.gradle was able to import the texture packer class:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.tools.texturepacker.TexturePacker
task texturePacker << {
    if (project.ext.has('texturePacker')) {
        logger.info "Calling TexturePacker: "+ texturePacker
        TexturePacker.process(texturePacker[0], texturePacker[1], texturePacker[2])
    }
}
```

please note that your desktop project's ext will need to have texturePacker defined:

```
project.ext {
    mainClassName = "your.game.package.DesktopLauncher"
    assetsDir = new File("../android/assets");
    texturePacker = ["../images/sprites", "../android/assets", "sprites"]
}
```

Comment: This is working but i had to change " to ' in the input/output path. Now how do i set the maxWidth and maxHeight? i tried 
def settings = new TexturePacker.Settings()
settings.maxHeight = 4096
settings.maxWidth = 2048, but it failes with general error.

Comment: I usually just [add a pack.json](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer#configuration) in my folders

Comment: An improvement to this solution would be to name the Strings in `texturePacker` more meaningfully rather than using an array.